# NoSQL Documents for Relational Like Data (Locations)

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have a list of locations, which currently in MySQL has a hierarchy above it like so Continent > Country > County/Region/State > Provence > Location. If I were to store these locations in a NoSQL store (like CouchDB). Would I just store the continent as the top level object and the rest as child arrays of objects for this continent. Then use map/reduce to create the various views for countries, counties etc. Is this the recommended structure for this kind of data? It would make each continent document very big?

```
{
  name: "Europe",
  type: "CONTINENT",
  countries: [
     { 
       name: "England" 
       counties: [...]
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a suggestion and speculation on my part, but I think I may have a good idea. (I would also highly recommend looking into [GeoCouch](http://vmx.cx/cgi-bin/blog/index.cgi/geocouch-the-future-is-now:2010-05-03%3aen,CouchDB,Python,Erlang,geo) for location-type data.)

If you want to proceed yourself, you can store each location with all of the levels of detail stored as attributes:

```
{
    "continent": "North America",
    "country": "United States",
    "state": "Texas",
    "city": "Houston"
}
```

I'm from the US, so I'm using what I would normally use for determining my location. (I noticed you used provence, county, etc. which can easily be incorporated into this model)

Anyways, the view function would look like this:

```
function (doc) {
    emit([doc.continent, doc.country, doc.state, doc.city], null);
}
```

This view will output:

```
{
    "key": ["North America", "United States", "Texas", "Houston"],
    "value": null
}
```

Now, I know this is redundant data, since it's stored like this for every location. That's OK, we're dealing with NoSQL, there's no need to continue thinking relationally. (that's why you're looking at another solution like CouchDB)

Anyways, you can use the view parameter `group_level` to "drill-down" into your locations. Using `group_level=1` will get you a view result grouped by Continent. `group_level=2` will group by Country, `group_level=3` will group by State, etc.

Using a reduce function can get you counts and other statistics for each of these groupings. I hope this helps!

Comment: Nice one thanks. Another question if I may. What if each of the area's has data about that area like. For example for England we have some textual information about the area for surfing. Ideally we wouldn't update every document that had England in it if we changed the text?

Comment: You could have a separate document type that only has continent and country, then you could use a separate view to bring in that document type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solutions creates a relational structure of some kind? Not that that's a problem, but that is what your suggesting?

Comment: For the ultimate in unnecessary optimization, you can replace `null` with the number `1` which will save 5 bytes per row. (`null` takes 7 bytes to encode but integers less than 256 only take 2.

Comment: The number `1` is good too because you can later quickly add a `reduce: "count"` reduction and get easy row counting.